# Que resulta más eficiente?

Tags: java, condiciones, eficiencia

Tengo una duda sobre la eficiencia de una aplicación si aplico `if`'s anidados o `if-else if` en un codigo:

Tenemos que llenar un `String` y existen 3 casos:

- `boolean` para ver si rellenamos el `String` o no
- `int` con el codigo del idioma para rellenar el `String`

¿Cuál de estos snippets es más eficiente?:

**ifs anidados**

```
String cantidadAproximada = "";
if (contrato.isAproximado()) {
    if (contrato.getIdioma().getId() == DBConstantsHelper.ID_IDIOMA_FR)
        cantidadAproximada = " Approx.";
    else
        cantidadAproximada = " Aprox.";
}
```

**if-else-if**

```
String cantidadAproximada = "";
if (contrato.isAproximado() && contrato.getIdioma().getId() == DBConstantsHelper.ID_IDIOMA_FR) {
    cantidadAproximada = " Approx.";
else if (contrato.isAproximado() && contrato.getIdioma().getId() == DBConstantsHelper.ID_IDIOMA_FR) {
    cantidadAproximada = " Aprox.";
}
```

Mi opinión es que, la primera opción es más eficiente y legible, ya que en el caso de `false` no realiza una segunda evaluación y se parece más a *mi* lógica de pensamiento.

También entiendo que con solo este caso no voy a mejorar la eficiencia de una aplicación pero es una duda que me ha surgido y quiero ser consecuente y codificar en consecuencia a partir de ahora dependiendo de la respuesta.

Comment: Si no me equivoco puede ser que estes buscando algo como el operador ternario? http://lineadecodigo.com/java/el-operador-ternario-en-java/. result = (condition) ? value1 : value2

Comment: @M.Mariscal no, hablo de eficiencia, no de legibilidad. Ademas un ternario aqui seria un autentico caos porque deberian ser 2 anidados...

Comment: Entonces leyendo la frase: _"Tenemos que llenar un String y existen 3 casos:"_ me viene a la cabeza un switch-cases, switch contrato.getIdioma().getId() { case DBConstantsHelper.ID_IDIOMA_FR: {...} case DBConstantsHelper.ID_IDIOMA_ES {...} }

Comment: Si tienes más condiciones que sean fijas de comparación contra un valor constante en tiempo de compilación, y son de 4 (o 5) o más entonces te convendría utilizar un `switch` en lugar de `if` por lectura de código y una mayor eficiencia en tiempo de ejecución.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ambos son igual de [eficientes](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eficiencia_Algor%C3%ADtmica), puesto que no hay bucles y por tanto se ejecutarán en tiempo constante (salvo que alguna de las llamadas no fuera constante).  El primero de los dos casos probablemente sea más *rápido* (que no eficiente) puesto que realiza una única vez las llamadas a funciones para obtener los valores por los que preguntas; para estar seguros, evidentemente, habría que medir tiempos.

Sin embargo, **nada de esto es relevante**. En este tipo de código deberías elegir **la opción más legible y más mantenible** en lugar de obsesionarte con *micro-optimizaciones* en código que se va a ejecutar poco.  Sólo si en el futuro detectas que este método es un cuello de botella cabría analizarlo para optimizarlo.

Pregúntate, pues, en lugar de cuál de los dos es más rápido, ¿cuál de los dos se adaptará mejor a cambios en los requisitos (p.ej.: nuevos idiomas)? ¿puedes encontrar un tercero que se adapte *todavía mejor* a los cambios?

Comment: pero hay diferencia de eficiencia, el primer solo hace una comprobación y en el segundo debe realizar dos. y uno es menos que dos, es decir más eficiente el método 1 si no se cumple lo primero.

Comment: @Webserveis 1 y 2 son ambos `O(1)`, por lo que en términos de [eficiencia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eficiencia_Algor%C3%ADtmica) son idénticos. En mi respuesta puedes leer que efectivamente el primero es más *rápido*, puesto que ejecuta menos operaciones, pero de nuevo, *es irrelevante hasta que se demuestre que hay un problema de rendimiento*.

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta de @Darkhogg me parece mas que acertada, quisiera agregar que la legibilidad también depende de la codificación, aunque la segunda es mas difícil de mantener, si la refactoriza quedaría mas fácil, por ejemplo:

```
String cantidadAproximada = "";
bool isAproximado = contrato.isAproximado();
String idIdioma = contrato.getIdioma().getId();
if (isAproximado && idIdioma == DBConstantsHelper.ID_IDIOMA_FR) {
    cantidadAproximada = " Approx.";
else if (isAproximado && idIdioma == DBConstantsHelper.ID_IDIOMA_FR) {
    cantidadAproximada = " Aprox.";
}
```

Comment: Siempre he escuchado que el switch es más eficiente que if, porque trabaja  con tablas de saltos (jump table), a tu respuesta yo le pondría un switch, en vez de un if, else-if.

Comment: la respuesta era mas dirigida a que se podía refactorizar, pero es muy bueno tu aporte